# How to use another connection Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have tried to use another Mysql connection in Laravel:

```
DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

But I need to use model like:

```
Equipment::all();
```

How to use another connection for model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model always uses the other connection you can declare it in your model.

```
protected $connection = 'mysql2';
```

If you need to do it dynamically you can do

```
Equipment::on('mysql2')->all();
```